# Issues Removing index.php from Mediawiki URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mediawiki

I have a php website (laravel) that is set to the root of a subdomain using a virtualhost. So http://subdomain.website.com will go to the laravel website. I want to be able to go to http://subdomain.website.com/wiki and it will direct to the mediawiki install. To do this is setup an alias within the virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    Alias /wiki "/var/www/mediawiki" 
    Alias /w "/var/www/mediawiki" 
   <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public"> 
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is working exactly the way i want it to work, but there is an issue. I want to remove index.php from the url. So that "/wiki/index.php/Main_Page" becomes "/wiki/Main_Page".

I tried using http://shorturls.redwerks.org/ which i found in other guides, but it isnt working for me. Any code generated will produce wiki/wiki/Main_page and even at that the page throws an error.

> The requested URL /wiki/wiki/Main_Page was not found on this server.

I have tried messing around with a large amount of different combinations with the url and cant get this to work. Since this website is a subdomain im not able to use wiki.domain.com. This wiki needs to be part of the subdomain. Anyone know what i need to do to make this work?

The end result i need is for this URL to bring me to the main page

> http://sub.domain.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Have you had a look at the official [guide for Apache/LiteSpeed servers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache)?

Comment: Yes, but there is something im missing and thats what i need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have mod_rewrite enabled and then you can use rules like this to remove index.php. You can use this in your .htaccess in Wiki folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wiki
#redirect index.php to non index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)index\.php
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
#internally rewrite request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Update: Ordinarily this should work for typical CMS' however mediawiki itself has a unique because of the using `wiki` and `w` folders.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aShort_URL/Apache

Depending on the mediawiki structure chosen, it would require a rule such as this

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This sort of worked. It is bringing me to a wiki page but it looks like there is some sort of loop. The url is like this .....wiki/Wiki/wiki/Wiki/wiki/Wiki/wiki/Wiki/wiki/Wiki/wiki/Wiki/wiki/Wiki/Main_Page

Comment: You must be leaving out some info because whey are there too wiki folders? Post exactly what you have in your .htaccess file in your question.

Comment: I have nothing other than what is posted above. Mediawiki isnt a standard website though. If i have the htaccess blank and visit /wiki it will redirect to /wiki/index.php?/Main_Page. So while the rewrite might be correct the code within the wiki isnt correct and im not sure what is missing to make it work.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: "/var/www/mediawiki/.htaccess". I have an apache alias setup to direct requests to "/wiki" to this directory.   I tried completely deleting the htaccess and editing the alias to have .index.php on the end. this is working but no css or images are displaying.

Comment: mediawiki has different types of URLs and that's why it's an issue. They have a special Apache section to show you how to setup rewrite because of the alias it uses. I updated my answer to provide you the info and where to go to fix it.